# custom checkbox with default value is not selected in Jira

Tags: jira

In Jira (5.1.3), I have created a custom (Multi) checkbox

I have defined only one option (Yes), and set the default value to Yes.

When you edit a jira, the checkbox is not pre-selected, even though the default is the same as the value for that checkbox.

Is this a bug in jira?  or is there something I need to do to get the checkbox pre-selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spoken with Atlassian (Jira) support, and know the answer.  The configuration of the issue, whether issues already exist, and the order you do things matters.

When you set the default value, jira detects the change and tells you that you need to reindex the issues.  But this does NOT set the default for existing issues though

You have to do re-index, and then select all the issues (using a filter) that should use the default, and manually do a bulk update and set their default value.

New issues after that should use the default automatically.